# Can no longer connect to private Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, networking

I set up a Minecraft server 1.7.10 on my personal server hosted on the Rackspace Cloud. The server is whitelisted, as it is intended only for my kids and me to play on. The server had been running fine for a couple of months. Then, we went away for the weekend, and when we came back, we could not log on. The server would send this message: "java.net.ConnectException connection refused".

So, I logged on to the host machine, killed the process, and re-started the Minecraft server. Still, no dice. I checked the whitelist - that looked good. I tried turning off whitelisting - still nothing.

Obviously, the client can reach the server - because of the Java message - so I don't think it is a port or firewall issue. I just can't figure out what the problem is, and why it would just start happening on its own. The only thing I can think of is that somehow the world got corrupted during a save at some point, and now something somewhere is garbled.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you made sure your server and your personal clients are running the same version of MC?

Comment: Note that the java exception comes from the client, and thus does not mean that the server has been contacted. In fact, this is the exact error you get if you're connecting to the wrong IP or port (among other reasons)

Comment: @shanodin - Yes, both the server and the clients are running 1.7.10.

Comment: @Quentin. Ah, thanks for the clarification. I should have realized that :).

Comment: To check if the server is actually running and its not due to a firewall issue, try checking if the port is open on the server. Use some online port checking tool to eliminate issues that could have occurred locally

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me with a different host, oddly enough you need to sign in to your host's website and chances are they need you to agree to the updated EULA system, THis was from 1.7.10 onwards and applies to all servers.

Now seeing that you are just using a server host and not specifically a gaming host you need to ftp to get to the server files and from there simply find the EULA.txt and Change eula=false to eula=true then Save/Upload the changed file and restart your server.

This definately works for 1.7.10 servers and if you haven't already done it this will be your issue.

once accepted you will be able to access it fine.

Comment: Thanks @Flaunting, but I don't think that is the problem. I do no think that Rackspace works that way.

Comment: That is how all servers work now unfortunately, in the server config files there is now an EULA.txt which has a field you need to set to true. @JeffFohl

Comment: @Flaunting There is *no* guarantee that this EULA.txt is there for each and every hosting on the planet, because it sure isn't. I know *at least* one place where you can get a hosting without this EULA.txt thing.

Comment: Well they break the rules set by Mojang, based on his host which isn't a gaming host the OP would have needed to install the server himself and the EULA.txt is generated when creating a 1.7.10 server, even when you do it on a home computer @Arperum if you know of a host that doesn't comply you should report them

Comment: Wait, this EULA.txt is part of minecraft? In that case I retract my words.

Comment: Yeah it was added in with 1.7.10 and is one of the main features of that update. all servers legally have to agree to this or they are not allowed to run

Comment: Thanks @Flaunting. I see what you are talking about now - but that is not the issue. The Minecraft server has always been 1.7.10, and I enabled the eula.txt when I originally set it up.

Comment: @JeffFohl can you check that it is still set to true

Comment: @Flaunting. Yes, it is still set to true.